# Best practice RSpec example formatting for a multiple "simple" expectations

Tags: testing, rspec, formatting

I'm tryna improve my RSpec skills following the bests practices.
I have a simple method `is_multiple_of_3_or_5?` and I'm implementing a test for it using  simple testing values. My first approach was:

```rb
describe '#is_multiple_of_3_or_5?' do
  context "when input is multiple of 3 or 5" do
    expect(is_multiple_of_3_or_5?(3)).to be true
    expect(is_multiple_of_3_or_5?(5)).to be true
    expect(is_multiple_of_3_or_5?(51)).to be true
    expect(is_multiple_of_3_or_5?(45)).to be true
  end
end
```

I like it because it's very short and the test cases are simple, so no need to complicate it.. But I've read in the [RSpec style guide](https://github.com/abinoda/rspec-best-practices#only-one-expectation-per-example) that it should be only one expectation per example.
So I refactored in 2 other ways:

One it per example:

```rb
describe '#is_multiple_of_3_or_5?' do
  context 'when input is multiple of 3 or 5' do
    it "is true for 3" do
      expect(is_multiple_of_3_or_5?(3)).to be true
    end

    it "is true for 5" do
      expect(is_multiple_of_3_or_5?(5)).to be true
    end

    it "is true for 51" do
      expect(is_multiple_of_3_or_5?(51)).to be true
    end

    it "is true for 45" do
      expect(is_multiple_of_3_or_5?(45)).to be true
    end
  end
end
```

Drying up with a `subject` block

```rb
describe '#is_multiple_of_3_or_5?' do
  context 'when input is multiple of 3 or 5' do
    subject { is_multiple_of_3_or_5?(input) }

    context 'when input is 3' do
      let(:input) { 3 }
      it { is_expected.to be true }
    end

    context 'when input is 5' do
      let(:input) { 5 }
      it { is_expected.to be true }
    end

    context 'when input is 51' do
      let(:input) { 51 }
      it { is_expected.to be true }
    end

    context 'when input is 45' do
      let(:input) { 45 }
      it { is_expected.to be true }
    end
  end
end
```

So I have 2 questions:

- In the case of theses 2 last versions, the test became really bigger, is it really worth it? Considering that the values tested are simple integers?
- Which one of these 2 versions are better formatted?

Thank you for anyone who could help me take better perspective on RSpec!